# Recursion loop does not start

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following piece of code:

```
count=0

countIt(){

cd "$1"

for d in "$1"; do
 if [ -d $d ]; 
   then
    count=$((count+1))
    countIt "$d"
 fi
done

}
```

And I am calling this function with a directory as an argument.

So what I'm trying to do here, is recursively count how many times this function will loop through directories located inside the directory I am passing in as an argument when calling the function.

I have only put directories into that initial folder to test the functionality but the if statement does not seem to be executing as true thus the recursion never happens.

I'm quite new to shell and I looked up some recursive functions online but I still can't figure out what I did wrong here so any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this for fun or do you actually want a count of the directories in a tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in a countdirs.sh file:

```
count=0

countIt(){
  for d in "$1"/*; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
      count=$((count+1))
      countIt "$d"
    fi
  done
}
countIt "$1"
echo "Found $count directories and subdirectories"
```

Then run:

```
chmod +x countdirs.sh
./countdirs.sh somedir
```

Where somedir is the directory to count subdirectories on.

Yet you could count by doing:

```
find "$1"/* -type d | wc -l
```

Run the first part (before the pipe | ), so you see the output, then you will understand that wc -l counts the number of lines from the piped output.

Comment: True, funny I did have it right on the find but forgot to fix up there ...
Thanks

Comment: Just adding the /* did not do the trick. What exactly does that mean? Also could you please explain the "-maxdepth 0 | wc -l" part of the find statement?

Comment: Updated my response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the recursion seems to be working. Counting the directories. I will adjust it to my code tomorrow and post an update. Hopefully it will work as well.